# Redshift stuck in resize mode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift cluster that has been operating without issue for months. All of my ETL jobs into Redshift started failing a few days ago. I narrowed the issue down to the Redshift cluster itself being in "resize mode". I can query just fine, but when I try to do any write operations I get:

> ERROR: Cannot execute write query because system is in resize mode
> Detail: System is in resize mode, and ONLY read-only queries are
> allowed to execute.

I understand what the error message is telling me.. But I don't understand WHY the problem is happening and how to get to the root of the issue. I didn't initiate any resize operations.

Redshift details:

- Status: "Available"
- Node type: dc2.large | 1 node | 160 GB
- Storage used: 0.32% (0.51 of 160 GB used)

Any ideas on what the issue could possibly be or where to look?

Comment: I would advise you never to use a 1x node cluster.  It's a bizzare, wierd animal - I'm sure absolutely off the beaten track for test effort - it's there for people to start a cluster at minimal cost to look around, not to do *any* actual real work on.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a resize schedule defined for the cluster?

Comment: @MaxGanzII Right, it's my dev cluster - I just figured since I've never seen this problem before and because there was no obvious indication of the issue it would be best to ask around. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @BillWeiner No, I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "fixed" this by resizing my cluster up to 2 nodes and then resizing back down to 1 node. This allowed me to write to Redshift again. I realize this isn't exactly an "answer" to the problem but more of a workaround.

If anyone else is playing around in a 1 node cluster and has this exact problem, this should fix it.